# Modify variable or struct inside a C function

Tags: c, function, variables, automata

I wanted to make a game of life in C to learn C, but it doesn't work. I just noticed that my code doesn't work when I try to modify a variable created inside a function, even if I try to modify it inside the same function.

When I pass val = 1 in comment, and color in comment, the code works
so val = 0 doesn't cause problem, neither color = {0,0,0,0} because it doesn't modify the variable.
How can I do to correct it ?

```
void next_grid(int nbc, int nbr,Cell tab[][120],Cell newtab[][120]){

    for (int y = 0; y<120; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x<120; x++){

            int nb_neighbors = count_neighbors(tab,120,120,y,x);
            int val = 0;
            Color color = {0,0,0,0};

            // When a cell is dead
            if (tab[y][x].val == 0)
            {
                if (nb_neighbors == 3)
                {
                    val = 1;
                    color = (Color)  {230,160,0,255};
                }
                else{
                    val = 0;
                    color = (Color)  {0,0,0,255};
                }   

            }

            {
                if (nb_neighbors == 2 || nb_neighbors == 3)
                {
                    val = 1;
                    color = (Color) {230,160,0,255};

                }
                else
                {
                    val = 0;
                    color = (Color) {0,0,0,255};
                } 
            }


            newtab[y][x] = (Cell) {val,x,y,color};
        }
    }   
    // swap array
    for (int y = 0; y<120; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x<120; x++){
            tab[y][x] = (Cell) newtab[y][x];
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "When I pass val = 1 in comment, and color in comment"?  I don't see what comments you might be referring to, and your function neither has parameters of those names nor tries to pass its local variables bearing those names to any other function.

Comment: I think you need to read about passing by value and passing by reference.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_value.htm

Comment: Overall, it is not clear to me what behavior is expected, or what is actually observed, and it seems like there is a lot more code presented than is likely to be needed to convey the actual problem.  Please help us to help you by preparing and presenting a [mcve] demonstrating the issue.